# What to do after a paper gets accepted in a Springer journal?

Tags: publications, journals

I recently got my paper accepted in an SCI indexed journal published by Springer.
The acceptance letter reached me 10 days back.
However, the acceptance letter does not contain any information on what are the next steps that are needed for getting the paper published.

Can someone please guide me what are next steps to getting my published in a Springer journal. How long does it take to get the paper appear online? Is there any dedicated helpline of Springer which can help me in this process?  If yes, how to find it?

**In other words, shall I just wait patiently for the journal to get back to me again or is it my duty to reach them?**

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like-how-should-i-interpret-a Does this answer your question? It includes a section post-acceptane.

Comment: @Allure; I checked that question, but I am unsure whether I need to reach them again or the journal will reach me. Also the journal did not ask for the TeX files yet. So I am confused

Comment: Did you send your TeX files when you submitted your paper? If so, then the journal already has them. Typically as well, you wait for the journal to finish the first proofs; they will contact you if they have any problems.

Comment: @Allure; I did not send my TeX files yet, neither did the journal ask for it yet, They only demanded a PDF  while submission

Comment: Are you *sure*? That would be surprising, because the editorial management systems I'm familiar with would request the source files and then generate the PDFs themselves. They'd then ask you to verify that the PDF actually display what is supposed to be displayed. Typesetting also cannot happen without the source files - if you really did not upload the source files during submission, then the journal really ought to have contacted you for them by now; you could ask them what's going on.

Comment: Clearly you skipped the ‘celebrate’ step, so everything is on hold?

Comment: @Allure; The editorial system while submitting  said that  "though the author may upload the TeX files now but right now it is not mandatory, only a PDF is required"

Comment: Acceptance is determined by the editorial board, but production (copy editing, typesetting, etc) is usually an entirely separate department; the two are not usually synced up in any way.  So it is not at all surprising that there could be a significant delay between acceptance and first contact from the production team.

Comment: @NateEldredge; Thank you very much for the information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not expected to do anything (or they would have told you). So, yes, wait patiently. If they don't contact you over an excessively long time period (say a month), you could contact the journal manager and ask if you have missed any communication.